# How to update Twitter status from behind a PROXY server? Twitterizer2

Tags: c#, twitter, twitterizer

I am using twitterizer2 for updating twitter status. Its working fine if i am NOT behind a proxy but behind i a proxy i am getting error. How to send proxy IP, port and then username and password for proxy server in twitterizer framework?

Currently i am using the following code..

```
tokens = new OAuthTokens();
            tokens.AccessToken = "some token";
            tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "some secret";
            tokens.ConsumerKey = "some token";
            tokens.ConsumerSecret = "some secret";

          TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> tweetResponse =  TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, message);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitterizer supports proxies by relying on built-in settings in .net. First of all, without making any changes, Twitterizer will use the proxy settings that are defined for internet explorer (also found under Internet Settings on the control panel).

If you wish to override the system-wide configuration settings, there are 2 ways to do it:
 1. Set the default proxy in the application's configuration file. (More information [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx))
 2. Provide a [WebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a32x5aw) value to the [Proxy](http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/html/P_Twitterizer_OptionalProperties_Proxy.htm) property of the [OptionalProperties](http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/html/T_Twitterizer_OptionalProperties.htm) class allowed by each method.

Comment: In your case, the OptionalProperties class requested is the [StatusUpdateOptions](http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/html/T_Twitterizer_StatusUpdateOptions.htm) class.